# Chromium Incognito mode automatically logs me in to website

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

I'm having a very weird problem with my chromium browser "Version 37.0.2062.120 (281580) (64-bit)"
I clear all the browsing data

- Browsing history

  - Download history
  - Cookies and other site and plug-in data
  - Cached images and files
  - Passwords
  - Autofill form data
  - Hosted app data
  - Content licenses

since the beginning of time. 
I exit the browser, open it again, use incognito mode go to a specific website and I'm automatically logged in even though I haven't even saved the log in credentials in the first place. I'm not sure if the issue is from chromium or related to the Vbulletin forums since the forum I'm visiting runs the version 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be possible... Either way, make sure chrome is closed and not running in the background. Then delete the `Chrome` folder in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Google\`. I'm assuming you're on Windows 7 or later. This will destroy all data that Chrome has ever had, but if you really did clear all data from beginning of time there should be nothing left you need. Even still, you probably don't want to do this if there ANY data you might want to get out of Chrome.

If you still get logged in automatically it's the server. If this fixes it, there was/is something wrong with Chrome.